# How can I parse raw email source and extract the HTML part?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rfc822, pantomime

In my iPhone app, I'm handed the raw source of an email, in RFC822 (or "eml") format. I'd like the HTML part of this message (if one exists).

Rather than attempting to parse it out myself and converting escape chars and so on, I thought I'd check to see if anyone knows of an objective-c library to do this for me.

In .NET, I've always used the [Mailbee](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) classes for anything email related, but I can't seem to find anything similar for cocoa.

Comment: I don't know if there is an ObjC specific library for this, but any C library that will compile to a static archive or that is meant to be added to a project would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at the [Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime) framework for Mac OS X. It provides a full fledged email package, including RFC822 parsing. It can be downloaded directly from [here](http://pantomime.sourcearchive.com/downloads/1.1.2/pantomime_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz).

As far as I know it has not been ported to iPhone, but it should give you a good starting point.

Claus